# Autoload Vendor with CakePHP 2.x and using class in folder vendor

Tags: cakephp, ups

I have get packpage UPS from page https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-ups-api.
This is save in app/vendor of cakephp 2.x.
How do I use them? T want to import folder of package just download and using many class in it.

Answer (score 2):

It's described, as almost everything else in the [official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

- [Loading Vendor files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files)
- [But better use composer to manage your packages](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer)

Go for composer and it is just a `composer require gabrielbull/ups-api` and the lib will be available and loaded through the autoloader.